# Child-view gets rendered twice

Tags: forward, zend-framework3

I've noticed that my child-view gets rendered twice for some reasons.
Here is a simple test-case:

Let's assume I've two controllers, ControllerA and ControllerB. I'm forwarding the action forwardTestAction from ControllerA to ControllerB and display the view returned from ControllerB as a child-view.

ControllerA::forwardTestAction()

```
public function forwardTestAction()
{
    $childView = $this->forward()->dispatch(ControllerB::class, [
        'action' => 'forward-test',
    ]);

    $mainView = new ViewModel();
    $mainView->addChild($childView, 'content');

    return $mainView;
}
```

ControllerB::forwardTestAction()

```
public function forwardTestAction()
{
    $number = new \stdClass();
    $number->a = 10.4;

    $view = new ViewModel([
        'number' => $number,
    ]);
    return $view;
}
```

Template forward-test.phtml of ControllerA

```
<?= $content; ?>
```

Template forward-test.phtml of ControllerB

```
<?php
    $number->a = $this->currencyFormat($number->a);
    echo $number->a;
```

The currencyFormat plugin throws an exception, because number gets formatted twice. The reason is because the child-view itself gets rendered twice.

That's a really weird behaviour and causes not only performance issues but also many other problems e.g. numberFormatting etc.

I'm doing something wrong?

Also I should mention that the html only gets outputted once, but the template gets rendered twice. Maybe it's just a weird constellation of my current setup. I also posted an issue on Github and they were not able to reproduce it.

Comment: This could just be the use of the variable name `content`. Try using a different variable name, e.g. `$view->addChild($child, 'test');` and `echo $test;` in the view. I have not tested this however.

Comment: what is $content an instance of?

Comment: I tried renaming $content variable, but it doesn't make a difference.
$content is a string - the rendered child-view template